# How can I preserve my child's painting made with edible paints?

Tags: paint, children

I want to keep the random splatter of paints my baby made when playing with paints for the first time.

The problem is that the paints are edible paints I made using corn-starch, water and food colouring. I assume these will go off / go mouldy over time.

Is there anyway to preserve this? Would Lamination work? Is there anything less plasticky looking I could do such as spraying the paper with something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dry the painting and keep it dry, it shouldn't mold.

However, corn starch does become brittle and probably will crumble off if the painting is handled. I suggest coating the whole painting with several light layers of a spray glue or acrylic spray varnish and let each layer dry thoroughly before applying the next.

However, food colors will vanish over time, especially if they are exposed to UV light. The biggest source of UV light is natural sun light, even through a window. So if you want to keep this painting for several years, unfortunately you'll have to store it in a dark place like a cabinet or a storage box.

If your baby is the next Picasso and this painting is very dear to you, you could consider framing it with a special UV blocking glass.

Comment: My experience of food dyes and kids crafts is that the colour isn't brilliantly stable over a small number of years even kept reasonably dark (not simple fading, but pink going brown, for example).  So even if you preserve the original, also take the best photos or scans you can as a backup. As digital photos are essentially free, a further suggestion is to get a picture of the baby with the picture - it's a better memory to talk about in a few years:  "you've always loved painting even as a baby"

Answer (score 2):

Take a photograph.

- It will last a lot longer than edible paints.
- It will be easier to keep.
- Easy to share with friends & family.

You can print it to go into an album or scrapbook.